# C++ Single value enums versus preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, performance, enums, coding-style

Very simple question about best practices and performance.  I know that it's a bad idea to use bare constants in your code directly (e.g. -1 meaning "unassigned").  I generally don't like using the preprocessor for such things if I can help it, since I don't like shouting (e.g. `#define UNASSIGNED -1`) and don't like breaking with the convention of putting preprocessor names in all caps.  So I've taken to using anonymous enums:

```
enum {
  Unassigned = -1
};
```

Question: Is there any runtime performance penalty for this compared to the preprocessor approach?  Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Have you considered static `const` variables? I'm not suggesting it, just questioning.

Comment: likewise, have you considered if in case you need multiple such constants, that somehow belong together, an enum class is a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no runtime performance impact - the compiler will know they're just the value `-1` in both cases.

However, I believe the best approach is to use a correctly typed constant for this. For example:

```
const int Unassigned = -1;
```

(Substitute your actual type for `int`, of course).

Comment: Agreed.  Now that you mention it, in C++11 it's probably even better to use `constexpr int Unassigned = -1;`

Answer (score 3):

There should be no performance impact. However, why not just `const int Unassigned = -1`?